# cleaning up dataframe column values with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm looking at a dataset where there's "City" columns and values in it are formatted like, for example,  Entity["City", {"Hefei", "Anhui", "China"}]. I want to clean up this column so that only the name of the city remains. In the case of the above example, I want everything removed except for Hefei. I'm trying to use rstrip and lstrip with regex. Even though my regex seems to be correct based on online regex debugger websites, but the code doesn't work.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
df['City'] = df['City'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(r'(Entity["City", {")').rstrip(r'(",\s"\w+"}])'))
```

I want the result to be just Hefei. But the result that I'm getting is :

```
Hefei", "Anhui", "China
```

lstrip seems to be working, but rstrip only removes "}] and not the rest of the characters that I need removed.

I was hoping someone could tell where I'm making a mistake, or show me a better way to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could do:

```
df['city'] = df['city'].str.extract('{"(.+?)"')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    city
0  Hefei
```

The pattern `'{"(.+?)"'` means extract everything between quotes after the first `'{'` matching as little text as possible.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think you could also tell me how to get the country portion of the text? I thought df['City'] = df['City'].str.extract('",\s"(.+?)"}') should do it, but it doesn't...

Comment: Is the country portion always the last one?

Comment: @kavm Try the following pattern `',\s+"([^"]+?)"}]`